# Different layout for iPhone and iPad in the same Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6

Xcode 6 supports the "universal" storyboard. This is very convenient. That means we only need one storyboard for iPhone and iPad if the layout of iPhone and iPad are the same.But here comes a question:

What if most of the layouts of iPhone and iPad are the same, only a few differences in only one or two UIViewControllers? How can we add different UIViewControllers in the same storyboard for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: What kind of differences are these?  Could they be added programmatically?  For instance, color, distance, or font could all be changed without needing two storyboards.

Comment: For example, I have a segment control. I want to add it to the navigation bar in iPad. But it will be below navigation bar in iPhone. I know I can add it programmatically. But it's more convenient to do in IB because of the bunch of layout constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1. Add a constraint for height of a container view (yellow part) in storyboard

[image]

2. My code: (Add to navigation bar if in iPad. And add to the container view and also set the constants of the constraint to 0)

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var segmentControl : UISegmentedControl!
   @IBOutlet weak var segContainer: UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var heightConstrains: NSLayoutConstraint!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Personnal", "Department", "Company"]) as UISegmentedControl

       if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
           self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentControl
           self.heightConstrains.constant = 0
       } else {
           self.segContainer.addSubview(self.segmentControl)
       }
   }
   ```

My case is quite simple. So it's not difficult to implement in code. But what about the very complicated case?